# Происхождение слова "матерый"

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слова "матерый" и является ли оно родственным слову "мать"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что слово "мать" - одно из древнейших в русском (и не только русском) языке, вероятно еще ностратической (допраиндоевропейской) общности. Проводить сравнительный генезис таких корней обычно не представляется возможным.
Но на современном уровне слова не родственны. Матерый (как и матерный) судя по всему, происходит от индовропейского корня "mat" с общим значением "взрослый", "сформировавшийся".

Comment: Что-то вы тут понаписали не совсем... *Матерый, как и матерный* - ???

Comment: @Morkovkin  Ой, пардон. Исправляю.

Comment: Французское Maitre - тоже тогда от взрослый, сформированный? Мастер-же - это вроде как человек с опытом...

Answer (score 1):

"Матёрый" происходит от латинского maturus - зрелый, взрослый. К mater (мать), как мне кажется, отношения не имеет: разные корни matur-/mater-, хоть и звучит похоже.

Comment: Не ново... Такой ответ есть.

Answer (score 0):

Это явно латинский корень.
Например во фрвнцузском mature (матюр) - зрелый, сформировавшийся, повзрослевший.

Answer (score -1):

В кинологии используются выражения "матёрый кобель", "кобель заматерел", но многие и не подозревают, что это означает "повзрослевший кобель", "кобель сформировался".

Comment: Каково происхождение слова?

Comment: По-моему, Вы сильно недооцениваете "многих". Вполне известное слово с понятным значением.